# Grep byte offset in consecutive lines of piped output

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to export the byte offset of a specific character on every line of a piped input.
For example, the output abc.txt:

```
....gugucaA....
.....guauAgggu..
.....ggguguAau..
```

should return:

```
11:A
10:A
12:A
```

I have tried using:

```
cat abc.txt | while read -r line; do grep -aob 'A'; done
```

As explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/7561/327888.

However, this only offsets the output and retains the cumulative byte offsets of all 'A's.

ie.

```
11:A
21:A
33:A
```

Am I missing an option? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while read -r line; do grep -ob 'A' <<< "$line"; done < abc.txt
```

Output:

```
10:A
9:A
11:A
```

Answer (score 3):

If you just need the offset:

```
$ awk '{print index($0, "A")-1}' ip.txt
10
9
11

$ perl -lne 'print index($_, "A")' ip.txt
10
9
11
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for multiple grep invocations. If your version of grep supports the `P` option you could do:

```
grep -Po "[^A ]+(?=A)" inputfile | awk '{print length}'
```

output:

```
10
9
11
```